# How to redefine large amounts of data quickly

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm currently writing an ASCII Command Prompt game engine and I am not sure how to redefine 256+ ASCII chars quickly. I am not up to the job of learning all 256 codes.

I was going about having a separate file with the variables to save space, but honestly I'm not upto the job of writing this:

```
char ascii_null = char(0);
```

differently 256 times.

Comment: Why do you need to create such variable? Your purpose is not clear here.

Comment: "Redefine" in what way? What problem are you trying to solve? And what is your question?

Comment: You know, Nethack had (has?) an awesome ASCII-only game engine and they didn't redefine any characters!

Comment: Did you know that when you write `'a'` for example, it automatically converts to its code? Or `'\0'` is `0`? So why would you need to define `char char_a = (char)0x61;` when you can simply write `'a'` anywhere you want?

Comment: Nit-picking: ASCII is 127 chars only + a null character.

Comment: I'm talking about the extended ASCII Standerd, look up an ASCII table somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard methods are to use #define or const to provide a name to values.  These will more efficient since you won't be changing the values after you define them.

```
#define ascii_null char(0)
#define ascii_bell char(7)
```

or

```
const char ascii_null = char(0);
const char ascii_bell = char(7);
```

The easiest way to write those lines would be to copy a table from say [here](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html) and pasting it into Excel.  Then use Excel to build the lines with a formula: `="const char ascii_" & A1 & " = char(" & B1 & ")"`

Comment: Thanks you helped me out of a tight spot.

Comment: Which would be more efficient in this situation? Const or #define?

Comment: `const` is your best bet in most cases since it has scope and type.  `#define` is too aggressive and will replace any occurrence of the name with the value, even if it is a member of a `struct` or `class`, which will cause syntax errors.